# Proof: Let $\mathbf{y}_{ij}$ be independently distributed as $N_p (\mathbf{\mu , \Sigma})$ , where $i = 1 , \ldots , n_j$ , $j = 1, \ldots , J$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Proof: Let $\mathbf{y}_{ij}$ be independently distributed as $N_p (\mathbf{\mu , \Sigma})$ , where $i = 1 , \ldots , n_j,$ $j = 1 , \ldots , J$

(a) Let $\mathbf{z}_{ij} = A\mathbf{y}_{ij}$ . Show that $U_z = U_y$ where

$$U_z = \frac{|SSE_z|}{|SSE_z + SSTR_z|}, \qquad U_y = \frac{|SSE_y|}{|SSE_y + SSTR_y|}$$

and $A$ is a $p\times p$ nonsingular matrix.

---

This doesn't make much intuitive sense to me.. I tried to start by finding $\bar{z}_{\cdot j}$ and $\bar{z}_{\cdot \cdot}$ and plugging into SSE, SSTR, and SST for $z$ and comparing them to those of $y$ but it doesn't seem to work this way..

Can someone give me advice on how to start this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There should presumably be a factor that cancels from the numerator and denominator.

Comment: I'm accustomed to seeing this with scalar observations. You have $\overline {y}_{\cdot j} = (y_{1j} + \cdots + y_{n_j j})/n_j$ and $$ \text{SSE} = \sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^{n_j} (y_{ij}- \overline y_{\cdot j})^2 \text{ and SSTr} = \sum_{j=1}^J n_j (\overline y_{\cdot j} - \overline y)^2. $$ Will you just take the square of the norm of a vector rather than the square of a scalar? But that doesn't feel right: I'm guessing you'll have a Wishart matrix: instead of $\|a\|^2 = a^T a$ you'll have a rank-one matrix $a a^T$ and the sum of all those terms is a Wishart matrix. Then by$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$Then by $|A|$ I surmise you mean $\left| \det A \right|. \qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\overline y_{\cdot j} = \frac{y_{1j}+\cdots + y_{n_j j}}{n_j} \text{ and } \overline y = \text{grand mean.}
$$
$$
\text{SSE}_y = \sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^{n_j} (y_{ij}- \overline y_{\cdot j}) (y_{ij}- \overline y_{\cdot j})^T \text{ and SSTr} = \sum_{j=1}^J n_j (\overline y_{\cdot j} - \overline y) (\overline y_{\cdot j} - \overline y)^T.
$$
These are $p\times p$ Wishart matrices.
\begin{align}
\text{SSE}_z = \sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^{n_j} (z_{ij}- \overline z_{\cdot j}) (z_{ij}- \overline z_{\cdot j})^T & = \sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^{n_j} A(y_{ij}- \overline y_{\cdot j}) (y_{ij}- \overline y_{\cdot j})^T A^T \\[10pt]
& = A \left( \sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^{n_j} (y_{ij}- \overline y_{\cdot j}) (y_{ij}- \overline y_{\cdot j})^T \right) A^T \\[10pt]
& = A\Big( \text{SSE}_y \Big) A^T.
\end{align}

You'll just be multiplying the numerator and the denominator both by $\left| \det (AA^T)\right| = (\det A)^2.$

Comment: Thank you greatly. May I ask what the process would be for $Ay_{ij} + b$ if b is a p-vector? Perhaps I'm overcomplicating it but I tried simply plugging into the equation for SSE and simplifying until everything but $SSE_y$ comes out but I can't seem to do it. Perhaps my fundamentals are a bit rusty. I've become a bit reliant on software and now I'm paying the price.

Comment: If $z_{ij} = A y_{ij} + b, $ then $$ \begin{align} & \overline z_{\cdot j} = \frac{z_{1,j} + \cdots+z_{n_j,j}} {n_j} = \frac{(Ay_{1,j}+b) + \cdots + (Ay_{n_j,j}+b)}{n_j} \\ \\ = {} & A\frac{y_{1,j} + \cdots + y_{n_j,j}}{n_j} + \frac{b + \cdots + b}{n_j} = A \overline y_{\cdot j} + b, \end{align} $$ and $b$ ends up canceling.